# opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory using Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, ide

I'm trying to test `OpenCV (3.0.0)` with `Eclipse IDE` (Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)) but for some reason I fail to successfully include all the library path.

Can you tell me how is it possible that the include directory is in the project explorer with the file `*opencv.hpp*` in it but still fails to find it during the build process? And how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what operating system you are using or how you installed OpenCV but I faced the same problem when installing OpenCV 3.1.0 on Ubuntu 15.10. I was following [these](http://embedonix.com/articles/image-processing/installing-opencv-3-1-0-on-ubuntu/) instructions.

It turns out that after I ran `make` I forgot to run `make install` to actually install the compiled libraries.

I'm not sure if this problem has anything to do with Eclipse.